# Win7 on virtualbox and full screen mode

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox

I've installed win7 on virtualbox on ubuntu 12.04. However, the full screen mode isn't perfect. I have black parts on both sides of the screen. I tried changing the resolution but nothing fits. 
Anyway to fix this?

By the way, my ubuntu is 64-bit (intel 4000 graphic card), and the my win7 is 32-bit. I'm not sure if this is the cause of the issue.

Comment: Have you installed the virtualbox extensions and guest additions?

Comment: no I just installed it from the software center. So could you kindly tell me how do I get these extensions and additions?

Comment: In 2024, [this link](https://www.nakivo.com/blog/make-virtualbox-full-screen/) helped me install those extensions. Afterward, there is an option _View_ -> _Auto-resize Guest Display_.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You need to install the VirtualBox guest additions. Start Windows in your Virtualbox, and from the Virtualbox menu select "Devices -> Install guest additions"

[image]

Guest additions allow you a more seamless integration with the Linux desktop. Not only will you be able to have a better resolution and automatically adjust the resolution to the X window size, but in addition your mouse pointer will no longer be trapped by the Windows host, you will be able to share folders and more. See [here](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#additions-windows).

Comment: I install that but nothing happened :(

Comment: SO unfair. Doing it in ubuntu is soo freakin hard.

Answer (score 6):

Open main window of VM - Virtualbox.
[image: Example 1]

Click `File` (upper left) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> - Preferences Display
Set Hint --> Screen Size the same as main system.

[image: Example 2]

Done.
Back to main window, left side choose virtual system you want to start.

Comment: It does not work for me.

Comment: Changing the "Maximum Guest Screen Size" option to "None" worked for me - if that doesn't work, try enabling 3D acceleration as well.

Comment: works on mac. my resolution system preferences -> display -> scaled which was 1280x800. Changed virtual box display settings to "hint" changed the input to 1280x800. 

Started the virtual box and clicked full screen. I also had to click the display button in the virtual box and enable "Auto-resize Guest Display".

Answer (score 1):

I had to rise videomemory and it worked!

[image]