# How to maximize screen in virtual box?

Tags: 14.04

I have lenovo laptop, with windows 8.1 installed. I have installed Virtual box on it, try to install ubuntu 14.04 on virtual box, it install successfully. But it work in 800 X 600 resolution, how can I make it full screen.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not necessarily a duplicate of the indicated question. The answer might be simply Host+F where Host is the Right Ctrl key by default but may have been changed/customized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is answered here: [Is there a way to make a fullscreen on VirtualBox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/314685/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-fullscreen-on-virtualbox)

You need to install the [Guest Edition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-virtualbox) first and can then simply press <kbd>HOST</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> within the guest for full screen mode.