# Resolution problems on 14.04- will not install guest additions

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, resolution

I started using a Ubuntu from Virtual Box today because I was interested in Linux (I am not that good in coding, however) and found the design to be appealing.


People say to install 'guest additions' to the computer, but whenever I try to I get an error saying I can't mount the disk image. 

How can I get the fullscreen effect? 


I am running:

Linux Ubuntu 14.04

Virtual Box from oracle

Does anyone have any idea how I can get past this?

#### Can you make it noob-friendly, as I just started Ubuntu today?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You installed `virtualbox`, but did you install `virtualbox-guest-additions-iso virtualbox-guest-dkms virtualbox-guest-utils`?

- `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-additions-iso virtualbox-guest-dkms virtualbox-guest-utils`

Here is an [Answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/314698/13247) that has instructions on how to make `virtualbox` fullscreen, as well as a [more detailed explanation of how to get Guest Additions installed](https://askubuntu.com/a/22745/13247).

Answer (score 0):

- 1. Go to the 'Launcher'.

  2. Hit the disk icon.

  3. Hit 'run software' in the top-right corner

  4. Wait for the software to finish downloading via terminal

  5. Reboot and hit 'Run full screen' from the  bottom

  6. You're done!