# Screen size problem for Ubuntu virtual machine

Tags: 18.04, virtualbox

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 on VirtualBox and the display is not covering the whole screen of the guest OS.

Comment: Did you install VirtualBox Guest Additions to your virtual machine?

Comment: yes, sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guest Additions is an image of a CD. It needs to be connected as a device to the VM and then launched from inside the Ubuntu guest OS.

From the VirtualBox client menu, choose *Devices* → *Insert guest additions CD image*. It will mount into Ubuntu. Once it does, run the installer from that CD/DVD image and reboot the system once it's installed.

That should allow your guest OS to resize itself properly.

Comment: It has solved my problem.

Comment: YAY! Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the VirtualBox window, you can go to *View* → *Switch to Fullscreen Mode*.

See this thread: [Is there a way to make a fullscreen on VirtualBox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/314685/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-fullscreen-on-virtualbox)

Comment: @user3140225 okay I will look into that, thank you